# Why can't I find the file location in the terminal?

Tags: ubuntu, backup

I am using the KUP backup system. To the right, in the KUP backup interface, it mentions the location of the backup is in `Backups\kup\...` but I cannot find the `\kup\` under the `\backup\` directory in the terminal. Is there a reason for that ?

Furthermore, when I try accessing it from the GUI, by going to **media/username/Exernal_backup** it says "*No bup repository found*".
Moreover, I can see that in the KUP it is under the following extension "*bup:///media/username/External_backup/kup...*"

The reason I am asking is that I would like to backup the external harddrive to another external harddrive using the same software. And if I cannot find the external backup directory how is it possible to then backup this harddisk using the same software (KUP backup system) or any other software for this matter?

[image: 't I]

Comment: Can you find anything in the logs? Maybe the backup failed and that's why it's not visible anywhere? The "device usage - unknown size" could indicate such, although I'm not familiar with this software at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The directory structure you're seeing in `/media/<redacted>/External_Backup/Backups` looks like a Git repository with some extras - and, sure enough, [Kup Backup System](https://store.kde.org/p/1127689/) is a backup scheduler and GUI front-end to [command-line tool `bup`](https://github.com/bup/bup), which uses some parts of Git and supplements it with some extensions of its own.

That means, your backup repository does not store multiple independent copies of a file that has been backed up several times and modified in between backups: it is more likely to store only the latest version in full, and the other versions as a list of differences (unless the file has been so totally modified that saving a new full copy would be more efficient). In turn, that means you need the appropriate tool to access the backup repository on the command line: `bup` or perhaps `git` for special cases.

Try running `bup ls` in the backup repository directory (i.e. either `/media/<redacted>/External_Backup/Backups` or its parent directory).